# Android load Html with custom font-face could not affect

Tags: android, html, webview

in this simple html i can see correct page with custom web font as @font-face, but in my application i have Webview and this font could not affect to text. page show with default phone font

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Shams test</title>
            <link href='http://www.fontonline.ir/css/Shams.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <style>
                 .myclass{
                 font-family:Shams,'Shams';
                 font-size:12px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="myclass">This is Test</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My sample code:

```
String test = "<html>" +
                        "<head>" +
                        "<style type='text/css'>" +
                        "@font-face {" +
                        "    font-family: MyFont;" +
                        "    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/bnazanin.ttf')" +
                        "}" +
                        "body {" +
                        "    font-family: MyFont;" +
                        "    font-size: medium;" +
                        "    text-align: justify;" +
                        "}" +
                        "</style>" +
                        "</head>" +
                        "<body>" +
                        "سلام دوستان" +
                        "</body>" +
                        "</html>";
                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", test + "", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Try to work around downloading and saving font on local storage. Then you need to modify your html code. Hope this will help you. I had issue with relative links to font in css but when I change to absolute links all works fine. Also I loaded html from assets folder.

Comment: Is this works for you right now? I looked at old code and it looks the same.

Comment: no sir. that doesnot work for me. fonts folder and font name with path is correct. but i dont know why doesnt work

Comment: Just checked same and it works fine. Used some other font. Did you forget to put font inside app/src/main/assets/fonts folder?